# pandas apply function to data grouped by day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, mean-square-error

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
date,value1,value2
2016-01-01 00:00:00,3,0
2016-01-01 01:00:00,0,0
2016-01-01 02:00:00,0,0
2016-01-01 03:00:00,0,0
2016-01-01 04:00:00,0,0
2016-01-01 05:00:00,0,0
2016-01-01 06:00:00,0,0
2016-01-01 07:00:00,0,2
2016-01-01 08:00:00,3,11
2016-01-01 09:00:00,14,14
2016-01-01 10:00:00,12,13
2016-01-01 11:00:00,11,13
2016-01-01 12:00:00,11,9
2016-01-01 13:00:00,17,21
2016-01-01 14:00:00,9,22
2016-01-01 15:00:00,10,9
2016-01-01 16:00:00,11,9
2016-01-01 17:00:00,8,8
2016-01-01 18:00:00,4,2
2016-01-01 19:00:00,5,7
2016-01-01 20:00:00,5,5
2016-01-01 21:00:00,3,4
2016-01-01 22:00:00,2,4
2016-01-01 23:00:00,2,4
2016-01-02 00:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 01:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 02:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 03:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 04:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 05:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 06:00:00,1,0
2016-01-02 07:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 08:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 09:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 10:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 11:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 12:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 13:00:00,1,0
2016-01-02 14:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 15:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 16:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 17:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 18:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 19:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 20:00:00,1,0
2016-01-02 21:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 22:00:00,0,0
2016-01-02 23:00:00,0,0
```

What I want to do is calculate the rmse between value1 and value2 per day.
So basically, I want to run the function 31 times (once per day), and the input would be the 24 entries of the day (one every hour)
I tried using

```
rmse(df.groupby([df.index.day]).mean().value1, 
    df.groupby([df.index.day]).mean().value2)
```

but it gave me a single value, and what I want is a list with the rmse of each day, such as

```
daily_rmse = [rmse01_01, rmse01_02, ..., rmse01_31]
```

Comment: Why are you calling `rmse` on the mean?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was trying to get some kind of visualisation of the data. Besides, the result I got on the mean was better than the result on the sum...

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. Why are you computing the rmse on sequence of means instead of computing it for each day?

Comment: Oh, that is actually why I am asking for help... I don't know how to apply a function to the sequence of days

Comment: Could you please provide a Python snippet to initialize a sample DataFrame? I don't feel like copying your data in line-by-line.

Comment: Gotcha. I can answer that if you show me a sample DF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sklearn`s `mean_squared_error`

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

df.groupby(df.date.dt.date).apply(
    lambda x: mean_squared_error(x.value1, x.value2) ** .5)

date
2016-01-01    3.494043
2016-01-02    0.377964
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep redoing the `groupby` and you need to compute `rmse` on each element of it, not on the sequence of means:

```
gb = df.groupby(df.index.date)
mean_by_day = gb.mean()
rmse_by_day = gb.std(ddof=0)
```

I suspect that the RMSE formula you are applying is exactly equivalent to the standard deviation normalized by the number of elements (not the number of elements - 1, as is default in Pandas).

You should now be able to access `mean_by_day.value1` and `std_by_day.value1` to get the values that you want.

The value I get for `mean_by_day` is

```
              value1    value2
2016-01-01  5.416667  6.541667
2016-01-02  0.125000  0.000000
```

Similarly, for `rmse_by_day` I get

```
              value1    value2
2016-01-01  5.139039  6.422481
2016-01-02  0.330719  0.000000
```

Note that the `date` field of the index is used rather than `day`, which could be repeated if your data went on for multiple months.

Comment: I am using sklearn's mean_squared_error(value1, value2) and applying there sqrt to calculate the rmse

Comment: I have run your suggestion, but it still gives me a single number... I am looking for a list of numbers, one entry per day, each one containing the rmse for each day...

Comment: So could you provide me with a runnable Python snippet to get that dataframe?

Comment: I've edited it so that it is importable by pandas with the ',' separator, is that ok?

Comment: That works. I am not sure where you are seeing one number. I have updated with the result that I am getting.